# Jenkins build failure ; not understanding jenkins log

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am having trouble understanding the error in the project

Although my build steps pass

```
02:40:40 api_1  | complete: 6 passing, 0 failing, 0 errors, 0 skipped, 6 total
```

It is failing. This is output from jenkins log

```
[root@ip-10-14-6-40 jenkins]# tail jenkins.log
Nov 14, 2018 2:40:35 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished DockerContainerWatchdog Asynchronous Periodic Work. 11 ms
Nov 14, 2018 2:40:36 AM jenkins.plugins.slack.StandardSlackService publish
INFO: Posting succeeded
Nov 14, 2018 2:40:46 AM jenkins.plugins.slack.StandardSlackService publish
INFO: Posting succeeded   
Nov 14, 2018 2:40:46 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun 
finish
INFO: tal-ci-test/spec #101 completed: FAILURE
Nov 14, 2018 2:40:46 AM 
org.terracotta.jenkins.plugins.postcompleted.PostCompletedRunListener 
onCompleted
INFO: The url to submit to is not valid, please check your global 
configuration
```

Comment: what is the value you have set for Jenkins URL ? The issue is `INFO: The url to submit to is not valid, please check your global configuration`. Meaning, you've issues with your configurations, specifically with URL. You can look into Manage  Jenkins -> Configure Systems

Comment: I have confirmed that the JENKINS URL under Configure Systems > Jenkins location is correct.